# Regex to match 2 or none?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have this regex to identify if the line contains two underscores:

```
\s*_{2}(\w+)
```

Any space, two underscores and then a word.  It turns out, I need to know also for no underscore at all, so I have:

```
\s*(\w+)
```

Optional spaces followed by a word.  Then I get the group 1 which is my word. So far so good.

The problem is the action taken when two underscores are used, is almost identical to the code when no underscore are use ( except that I raise a flag )

```
if( s =~ uderscore ) { 
   takeGroup( 1 )
   yada yada 
   flag = true
} else if( s =~ noUnderscore { 
  takeGroup( 1 ) 
  yada yada 
   flag = false 
}
```

I think there must be a better way instead of duplicating the whole regexp and test with and with out.

Comment: `\s*_{2}?(\w+)` Ought to do it for you.

Comment: I think the problem here will to to know if I need to raise the flag or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this regex instead:

```
\s*(_{2})?(\w+)
```

Then simply test for the presence of the first group -- if it's there, the underscores were present.  What was group 1 will then become group 2.

Comment: Correction ( at least in my test ) if not present the first group is null.

Answer (score 3):

```
\s*(__)?(\w+)
```

`(__)?` is an optional group of two underscores. Note that the word will be in group 2 now instead of 1. You could use a non-capturing group `(?:__)` instead if you wanted to not change the group numbering.

Comment: Ahh yeap, thata was my other problem ( I forgot to mention ) when I group it, the number changed. So I have to add extra check to know if there is 2 or 3 groups and slide accordingly?  What's what "non-capturing group" all about? Because I need to know ( to raise the flag ) but I don't want to change all the numbers ( if I can help it ) :P

Comment: What's the difference between using a non-capturing group and not setting the group at all?

Comment: The group is to be able to make the underscores optional together (if you just did `__?`, then only the second underscore would be optional).